# Python - sorting a tuple, characters over numbers

Tags: python, sorting, time, numbers, character

I have a list of time values like this:

```
lst = ['3min', '9min', '16:21', '16:36', '16:51', 'now']
```

If the time is 00 from current time the value "now" is given, if the time is less than 10min from current time, the number of minutes is given. If the time from current time is more than 10 minutes, the actually time stamp is given.

The problem is that the sorting function is sorting numbers before characters. This way the "now" value, is displayed last - I would like this value to be displayed first, while the other "min" and time stamp should be sorted as usual! How can I solve this?

Comment: And what if `now` is a time **later** than `16:51`?

Comment: Use a custom `key` function? However not sure how you could handle both relative and absolute times. Do you want a function that sorts the list differently depending on the current system time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to actually parse out those times into something that is sortable:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

def value_to_time(val):
    if val == 'now':
        return datetime.now().time()
    if val.endswith('min'):
        return (datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=int(val[:-3]))).time()
    hours, minutes = map(int, val.split(':'))
    return time(hours, minutes)
```

then sort using that function as a key:

```
sorted(lst, key=value_to_time)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
>>> def value_to_time(val):
...     if val == 'now':
...         return datetime.now().time()
...     if val.endswith('min'):
...         return (datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=int(val[:-3]))).time()
...     hours, minutes = map(int, val.split(':'))
...     return time(hours, minutes)
... 
>>> lst = ['3min', '9min', '16:21', '16:36', '16:51', 'now']
>>> sorted(lst, key=value_to_time)
['now', '3min', '9min', '16:21', '16:36', '16:51']
```

This *is* dependent on the current actual time, if my local time was not around 15:20-ish but 90 minutes later the `now` and relative times would be sorted towards the end of the list instead.

The alternative would be to use minutes-since-midnight integer values and use **negative** values for your relative strings:

```
def value_to_time(val):
    if val == 'now':
        return -11
    if val.endswith('min'):
        return -11 + int(val[:-3])
    hours, minutes = map(int, val.split(':'))
    return hours * 60 + minutes
```

Now `now` is -11, any relative minutes are mapped to `-10` through to `-1` and any absolute time to `0` through to `1440`.

The result is still the same, but the sort order is stable regardless of the system time:

```
>>> def value_to_time(val):
...     if val == 'now':
...         return -11
...     if val.endswith('min'):
...         return -11 + int(val[:-3])
...     hours, minutes = map(int, val.split(':'))
...     return hours * 60 + minutes
... 
>>> sorted(lst, key=value_to_time)
['now', '3min', '9min', '16:21', '16:36', '16:51']
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martijn Pieters, I went for your first suggestion!